# Typing a function decorator with conditional output type, in Python

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a set of functions which all accept a `value` named parameter, plus arbitrary other named parameters.

I have a decorator: `lazy`. Normally the decorated functions return as normal, but return a partial function if `value` is None.

How do I type-hint the decorator, whose output depends on the value input?

```py
from functools import partial

def lazy(func):
    def wrapper(value=None, **kwargs):
        if value is not None:
            return func(value=value, **kwargs)
        else:
            return partial(func, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@lazy
def test_multiply(*, value: float, multiplier: float) -> float:
    return value * multiplier

@lazy
def test_format(*, value: float, fmt: str) -> str:
    return fmt % value

print('test_multiply 5*2:', test_multiply(value=5, multiplier=2))
print('test_format 7.777 as .2f:', test_format(value=7.777, fmt='%.2f'))

func_mult_11 = test_multiply(multiplier=11)  # returns a partial function
print('Type of func_mult_11:', type(func_mult_11))
print('func_mult_11 5*11:', func_mult_11(value=5))
```

I'm using `mypy` and I've managed to get most of the way using mypy extensions, but haven't got the `value` typing working in `wrapper`:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Any, Optional
from mypy_extensions import DefaultNamedArg, KwArg

R = TypeVar("R")
P = ParamSpec("P")

def lazy(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[[DefaultNamedArg(float, 'value'), KwArg(Any)], Any]:
    def wrapper(value = None, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R | partial[R]:
        if value is not None:
            return func(value=value, **kwargs)
        else:
            return partial(func, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

How can I type `value`? And better still, can I do this without mypy extensions?

Comment: Probably you should use `typing.overload`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I did try this but couldn't get it working inside of the decorator? I will retry!

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible options here. First is "more formally correct", but way too permissive, approach relying on `partial` hint:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from functools import partial
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Any, Optional, Protocol, overload, Concatenate

R = TypeVar("R")
P = ParamSpec("P")

class YourCallable(Protocol[P, R]):
    @overload
    def __call__(self, value: float, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R: ...
    @overload
    def __call__(self, value: None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> partial[R]: ...

def lazy(func: Callable[Concatenate[float, P], R]) -> YourCallable[P, R]:
    def wrapper(value: float | None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R | partial[R]:
        if value is not None:
            return func(value, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            if args:
                raise ValueError("Lazy call must provide keyword arguments only")
            return partial(func, **kwargs)
    return wrapper  # type: ignore[return-value]

@lazy
def test_multiply(value: float, *, multiplier: float) -> float:
    return value * multiplier

@lazy
def test_format(value: float, *, fmt: str) -> str:
    return fmt % value

print('test_multiply 5*2:', test_multiply(value=5, multiplier=2))
print('test_format 7.777 as .2f:', test_format(value=7.777, fmt='%.2f'))

func_mult_11 = test_multiply(multiplier=11)  # returns a partial function
print('Type of func_mult_11:', type(func_mult_11))
print('func_mult_11 5*11:', func_mult_11(value=5))
func_mult_11(value=5, multiplier=5)  # OK
func_mult_11(value='a')  # False negative: we want this to fail
```

Last two calls show hat is good and bad about this approach. `partial` accepts any input arguments, so is not sufficiently safe. If you want to override the arguments provided to lazy callable initially, this is probably the best solution.

Note that I slightly changed signatures of the input callables: without that you will not be able to use `Concatenate`. Note also that `KwArg`, `DefaultNamedArg` and company are all deprecated in favour of protocols. You cannot use paramspec with kwargs only, args must also be present. If you trust your type checker, it is fine to use kwarg-only callables, all unnamed calls will be rejected at the type checking phase.

However, I have another alternative to share if you do not want to override default args passed to the initial callable, which is fully safe, but emits false positives if you try to.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from functools import partial
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Any, Optional, Protocol, overload, Concatenate

_R_co = TypeVar("_R_co", covariant=True)
R = TypeVar("R")
P = ParamSpec("P")

class ValueOnlyCallable(Protocol[_R_co]):
    def __call__(self, value: float) -> _R_co: ...
    
class YourCallableTooStrict(Protocol[P, _R_co]):
    @overload
    def __call__(self, value: float, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> _R_co: ...
    @overload
    def __call__(self, value: None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> ValueOnlyCallable[_R_co]: ...


def lazy_strict(func: Callable[Concatenate[float, P], R]) -> YourCallableTooStrict[P, R]:
    def wrapper(value: float | None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R | partial[R]:
        if value is not None:
            return func(value, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            if args:
                raise ValueError("Lazy call must provide keyword arguments only")
            return partial(func, **kwargs)
    return wrapper  # type: ignore[return-value]

@lazy_strict
def test_multiply_strict(value: float, *, multiplier: float) -> float:
    return value * multiplier

@lazy_strict
def test_format_strict(value: float, *, fmt: str) -> str:
    return fmt % value

print('test_multiply 5*2:', test_multiply_strict(value=5, multiplier=2))
print('test_format 7.777 as .2f:', test_format_strict(value=7.777, fmt='%.2f'))

func_mult_11_strict = test_multiply_strict(multiplier=11)  # returns a partial function
print('Type of func_mult_11:', type(func_mult_11_strict))
print('func_mult_11 5*11:', func_mult_11_strict(value=5))
func_mult_11_strict(value=5, multiplier=5)  # False positive: OK at runtime, but not allowed by mypy. E: Unexpected keyword argument "multiplier" for "__call__" of "ValueOnlyCallable"  [call-arg]
func_mult_11_strict(value='a')  # Expected. E: Argument "value" to "__call__" of "ValueOnlyCallable" has incompatible type "str"; expected "float"  [arg-type]
```

You can also mark `value` kw-only in `ValueOnlyCallable` definition if you'd like, I just don't think it is reasonable for a function with only one argument.

You can compare both approaches in [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=f0d994cc5194d4d3f3eedf3e558b66c3).

If you do not want to use an ignore comment, the verbose option below should work. However, I do not think that verbosity is worth removing one ignore comment - it's up to you to decide.

```py
def lazy_strict(func: Callable[Concatenate[float, P], R]) -> YourCallableTooStrict[P, R]:
    @overload
    def wrapper(value: float, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R: ...
    @overload
    def wrapper(value: None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> ValueOnlyCallable[R]: ...
    def wrapper(value: float | None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R | ValueOnlyCallable[R]:
        if value is not None:
            return func(value, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            if args:
                raise ValueError("Lazy call must provide keyword arguments only")    
            return partial(func, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Here's also Pyright [playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwFgAoF0SKRUgYyTDAA29bHgJFcxQlmIC24aEgCeuLKQDmI-ISgBhGQOIAjAWgA0UACrK0ANUnmACpOIQAyrjTdH4Pt0HmwADc0EAEwYgATcx06bmo0UniWFhgAJRg-KABeS2s7EAAKACI0jLAi8z9AyWlSJCyLEAQ0AEoWVOzcj3zi1KK25gdOpxAXd09ih37k1mZuA3phOwFmgHlSAUU9AQNjNAKHHzA-AQBtUr8AXRaALhYoB6gItGBYDP04Avo0AWBzapWaBunDC1BaUAAtAA%2BWDpPzAgB0SPujxm82IiygAE0wKhtrsTBZ%2BK4kCAsLwDkcTqcHOYLmBrndmI8oAABIIhUERFEPZ6vOBxHafb6-f4yZrA4CgpDmABUkjU9GBDgRCvoctlAGsAO5q5UInVq8HQ2FlRHI5mPdnBULhbmW3kvN6CgTCn5-KAAiVQABydDQnT9pDMUHlIEV%2BrVGsN4aVUBVMcVxphyzWGy2%2BiMJnOcIZ5oRaIWwhxeMze0plGOghp5lSjJ5bI5tsiDb5zo%2BMC%2B7rFgMl0rlevjqtj0d1sf1ifoyagqXzDetnLtradAo7XdFnvFQN9-sD-oH46HUdDWrHEaHk%2BnEikMlOdbnsxYbYMAC9FAUuNxgfis2hTjEeHiRIkD-KVwhleNLlra5IRhEsQB-PYaxnS4mRZNttVGXAPEKL1tzA6goAAHx3YM92DA9zxVY9ZVPQcEzPKdYJnYioGvGhb3vBsWSwV48OwYQKCIIMgW4llHnQFAQFITgEB4Ao8Mo9UT0vMSHh%2Bb40PE7TJNQGT2OkAQPzkrxQxoujYwGFldOkqBMOIbCQgeABiKAlA8YEsDUCh0FOGzSAhPDLhmJ8nVfRQYHoUlySQYyeG-MtswAuIQOA0D%2B0g6Dp3gxDCWJaLeGQriHUbG0uWXV57Mc3Ctz7cClMjEcVMYidGOnWcoCRAsSoXZt7XQp0qpwhTatIgMchEhqjya2jJ1ao1mNTNB1k2XK-3vTqLQGyqsOGvC6sIkiRPIkMwyo4dFVHeiDTa5iOhIpaVozHZfzvVC1OwPitwEqAhLGrTtOstApJkz8RsBJSrssj6NNEkrAagfy2MkDijM-SHmqNBskaGkIZlZcLQteECopgCAEAEGhcE2cHvQIiDZXMcnKawamsBCA6kGnemAcR4G9M3QFQygZmqYEdmQHxwnmDbEmkHgAgIGoWn8IyxnOAgJBgSikBpx13mkeATWoAAUkF5oZlwMk6gKAByOWyYpsXFCgABWWUACYblt8wHdF1mabwrJXaZp2A4lrIPZaAYrdUWL7bQUngEVwiAHYEVTzOSGEBEPeAb3fcT%2BXk5AJXYqD9PM9T8wjfqW2Tdz4BbejmZP0dymYAARk7zo-bD6n339tmQiybvwSgVz-OEYhkZvARZJ4Gg6BYWObdtqwPCgMBXjb0Wu87gu3OsOLuHb%2BWx5j63493p397d2Vu8Pm%2BO%2B7lXg5b5hn-Pzu35DkX%2B-FiPV249XKrAANJsBMmffeb9bbEGbi5KAAAxGQ3xfpoDUNQLAwRgTagDLqOobkAAWWBhB8E4MQLAshZgE2IG%2BSKBUkBEzckXM%2BAcIo6xiirTmcpQ4s2HiATm3NpQG35rZfisp-78MAZLGh4UGFkl4Mwh2Jcy4KK4ftEE9VQw101trUketSSiJBhrIgZs8KWyvnbPu0iXbuy9j7FhpMh6bHURSIOf8XERyjpfOO1jWGqLThnLOGJOp50PiolO8tOHuK3FkSumddF1wbnnZuAxIE8Ggd3NxRAcg2OdjkgoXiR5j0QVPEgs9UYL14LQUgK8rHr2sFvHeUC96P0ce5fYX9945I-qva%2BrTb7d3vu0mugyX6d0KR4j%2B3TskxPLnEzxACI7AMQSgoQAZ8D0CwDQHBUBwEkCIE0OoOAQyGGQL9SgJAdhgDwREKAhgXYQGUIoBEUAACiwIACqwYAAeHheBoHuZqNAihtQEHuQqBAEAEhECKMUkARROAECgCUd4QoYBIu3qix66Y1pIqgKcF0EIFTBU-uM7%2BUy4lwIQRPD5-zPAgQiG8z5UAACC4ZoWwtRXhJF5C0UujgFi14RRcWrUSmgJFRDQmqD8HgLBewj6byKDrIoABuKAaAGWAvuUUemBLTgKghJ0slQA), because `mypy` failed to find a mistake in my original answer and Pyright did.

Comment: Amazing stuff, thanks @STerliakov! Could you expand on the use of the covariant `_R_co`, it's not clear to me what that's doing? Also I don't want to override values, so the 2nd solution seems perfect.

Comment: @Jetpac `_R_co` is just another type variable. It must be covariant, because it's used only as a return type. This basically means that `ValueOnlyCallable[int]` is assignable to `ValueOnlyCallable[float]`. If you try to use invariant `R` instead, `mypy` will yield a helpful error message.

Comment: is there a way around not ignoring the wrapper output with `# type: ignore[return-value]` ?

Comment: @Jetpac Wow, there are a plenty of ParamSpec-related `mypy` bugs. I missed `P.args` everywhere in my answer, and `mypy` didn't dare to complain. Yes, it's possible to go without ignore comment - you'll need to provide same overloads for `wrapper` definition. I'll add this to answer a bit later and fix the mistake.

Comment: @Jetpac I have added a way to proceed without ignore comment.